# Adding a caption to an equation in LaTeX

Tags: latex

Well, it seems simple enough, but I can't find a way to add a caption to an equation.
The caption is needed to explain the variables used in the equation, so some kind of table-like structure to keep it all aligned and pretty would be great.

Comment: By equation, do you mean a theorem?

Comment: Actually I mean a formula, with some variables, and then some text below it explained what each variable means.

Comment: This is often accomplished by simply providing the explanation in the text---for this, latex provides in-line math mode, the formula environment, the theorem environments, etc. If you want to set your work off from the text, use the float package as explained below.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The `\caption` command is restricted to floats: you will need to place the equation in a figure or table environment (or a new kind of floating environment). For example:

```
\begin{figure}
\[ E = m c^2 \]
\caption{A famous equation}
\end{figure}
```

The point of floats is that you let LaTeX determine their placement. If you want to equation to appear in a fixed position, don't use a float. The `\captionof` command of the [caption package](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf) can be used to place a caption outside of a floating environment. It is used like this:

```
\[ E = m c^2 \]
\captionof{figure}{A famous equation}
```

This will also produce an entry for the `\listoffigures`, if your document has one.

To align parts of an equation, take a look at the [`eqnarray` environment](http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/teTeX/latex/latex2e-html/ltx-223.html), or some of the environments of the [amsmath](http://www.ams.org/tex/amslatex.html) package: align, gather, multiline,...

Comment: Adding an unwanted entry in `\listoffigures` is a dealbreaker for this approach IMO

Answer (score 12):

You may want to look at http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/float/ which allows you to define new floats using `\newfloat`

I say this because captions are usually applied to floats.

Straight ahead equations (those written with `$ ... $`, `$$ ... $$`, `begin{equation}...`) are in-line objects that do not support `\caption`.

This can be done using the following [snippet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97034/149720) just before `\begin{document}`

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\newaliascnt{eqfloat}{equation}
\newfloat{eqfloat}{h}{eqflts}
\floatname{eqfloat}{Equation}

\newcommand*{\ORGeqfloat}{}
\let\ORGeqfloat\eqfloat
\def\eqfloat{%
  \let\ORIGINALcaption\caption
  \def\caption{%
    \addtocounter{equation}{-1}%
    \ORIGINALcaption
  }%
  \ORGeqfloat
}
```

and when adding an equation use something like

```
\begin{eqfloat}
\begin{equation}
f( x ) = ax + b
\label{eq:linear}
\end{equation}
\caption{Caption goes here}
\end{eqfloat}
```

Answer (score 12):

As in this [forum post by Gonzalo Medina](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6343), a third way may be:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionType{equ}[][]
%\captionsetup[equ]{labelformat=empty}

\begin{document}

Some text

\begin{equ}[!ht]
  \begin{equation}
    a=b+c
  \end{equation}
\caption{Caption of the equation}
\end{equ}

Some other text
 
\end{document}
```

More details of the commands used from package [`caption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption): [here](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf).

A screenshot of the output of the above code:

[image: screenshot of output]

Comment: This added "1: " at the beginning of my caption, but my equation is numbered (5). How can I remove the "1: " from the caption? Also, the link is dead

Comment: This is how. Instead of `caption` use `caption*`: `\caption*{Eq. 5: my text}`

Comment: @MattS great! Thank you for enriching this answer and the link is now updated!