# How to create own and fancy \sub<float> command

Tags: latex, label, counter, caption, subfigure

I'm using packages `subfigure` and `float` to create figures and tables that I want to create and I'm trying to create my own environment `graph` with its own counter and caption ([solved there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149479/adding-a-caption-to-an-equation-in-latex), thanks to dmckee). Now I'd like to create `\subgraph` command which will do exactly the same as `\subfigure` command.

I tried create my own command with propreate counter ([Assisted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903254/how-to-define-in-latex-a-new-counter-that-includes-the-chapter-number-too), thanks to Alexey). But problem appears with using `\ref` command. Reference to `\subfigure` returns *2.1(a)* but reference to `\subgraph` returns *1*.

As I tried to find out how to solve this I read `subfig` manual, where I've found `\newsubfloat` command with an example. First error was in use of `subfig`'s commands in `subfigure` and I got stuck there. If I use `subfigure` I can access `\subfigure` but can't force `\subgraph` working, when I use `subfig` I can acces `\subfloat` in `graph` but not in `figure` and `\ref` returns *1.0a* instead of *1.1 (a)*.

definition by `subfig` package:

```
\newfloat{graph2}{tbph}{lom}[chapter]
\restylefloat*{graph2}
\floatstyle{plain}
\floatname{grap2}{Graph2}
\captionsetup[graph2]{position=top}
\newcommand{\listofGraphs}{\listof{Graph2}{List of Graphs}}
\newsubfloat[position=bottom,listofformat=subsimple]{graph2}
```

definition my own `\subgraph`

```
\newfloat{graph1}{H}{lop}[chapter]
\floatname{graph1}{Graph1}
\newcounter{GraphOne}[graph1]
\def\theGraphOne{\alph{GraphOne}}
\newcommand{\subgraph}[2][]{
\captionof{subGraph}{#1} #2
}

\newfloat{subGraph}{H}{lop}[graph1]
\floatname{subGraph}{}
```

Please help me with understanding how `\label` and `\ref` commands work (I think my solution collapses because `\label` is before `\caption`) and/or with forcing `subfig` package to work as I want.

Thank you for any idea and be merciful to my english.

Crowley

Improvement:

By using `caption` package I can create new counter (`subGraph`) and use it outside its environment. Only way how to have both counter (subgraph and graph) correcly referred is using `\captionof{graph}` before `\subgraph`.

So, my new question is: How to execute `\captionof{graph}` before subgraphs and typeset in below them? And how to force `\ref` to show 1.1-a instead of 1.1.1

Atachements:

Code for `subfigure`: (Returns `<chapter>`.`<figure>` (`<subfigure>`) correct.

```
\begin{figure}
\subfigure[sub-caption]{\includegraphics{fig1}\label{fig:1}}
\caption{main caption}
\end{figure}
\ref{fig:1}
```

Code for `subfig`: (Returns `<chapter>`.`<graph2>-1<subfigure>`) incorrect.

```
\begin{graph2}
\subfloat[sub-caption]{\includegraphics{fig1}\label{fig:2}}
\caption{main caption}
\end{graph2}
\ref{fig:2}
```

My code: (Returns `<chapter>`.`<graph1>`.`<subgraph>` but caption shows the same "adress")

```
\begin{graph1}
\captionof{graph1}{main caption}
\subgraph[sub-caption]{\includegraphics{fig1}\label{fig:3}}
\end{graph1}
\ref{fig:3}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `subfig` solution should work (`subfigure` is deprecated anyway).  The issue with the wrong references might have to do with you [using `\label` incorrectly](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=crossref).  You must have the `\label` command *after* the `\caption`, or as a part of it:

```
\begin{figure}
\caption{A Figure}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}
```

or

```
\begin{figure}
\caption{A Figure%
\label{fig}}
\end{figure}
```

*Edit*: the following "works for me".  As I said, the `\label` is after the `\caption`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\newfloat{graph2}{tbph}{lom}[chapter]
\restylefloat*{graph2}
\floatstyle{plain}
\floatname{grap2}{Graph2}
\captionsetup[graph2]{position=top}
\newcommand{\listofGraphs}{\listof{Graph2}{List of Graphs}}
\newsubfloat[position=bottom,listofformat=subsimple]{graph2}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test s}

\begin{graph2}
\subfloat[sub-caption]{\fbox{Fig 1}}
\caption{main caption}
\label{fig:1}
\end{graph2}

\begin{graph2}
\subfloat[sub-caption]{\fbox{Fig 2}}
\caption{main caption}
\label{fig:2}
\end{graph2}

Graph~\ref{fig:1} is the first graph, and~\ref{fig:2} is the second.

\end{document}
```

This produces:

```
Graph 1.1 is the first graph, and 1.2 is the second.
```

Comment: Yes I agree with the position of `\label` command AFTER `\caption`. I have no problem with standard floats, the point is in `\subfloat` and refering to it. I'm used to using \subfigure[sub-caption]{\includegraphics{}\label{fig:1}} \caption{main caption}\label{fig}

Comment: Hmm. I am not sure I understand.  If you have a small example document that shows your problem, please post it here.

Comment: I've updated question with my progress and part of code. My test `.tex` file is very hard to read

Answer (score 0):

I can't elaborate right now, but you want to use \refstepcounter instead of \addtocounter.

Comment: Maybe I didnt write it clearly. Is there any way how to tell `\label` "Forget chapter/section counter and store the GraphOne"?