# Adding an equation or formula to a figure caption in LaTeX

Tags: latex, mathematical-typesetting

I have a figure in LaTeX with a caption to which I need to add a formula (`equation*` or `displaymath` environments). For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tbph]
    \begin{center}
        %...
    \end{center}
    \caption{As you can see
            \begin{displaymath}4 \ne 5\end{displaymath}
    }
    \label{fig:somefig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This makes pdflatex angry, though it will produce a PDF.

```
! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.9    }
```

What's the right way to go about adding an equation to a figure caption?

**NOTE**: Please do not suggest simply using the `$ ... $` math environment;
the equation shown is a *toy* example; my real equation is much more intricate.

**See also**:

- [Adding a caption to an equation in LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149479/adding-a-caption-to-an-equation-in-latex) (the reverse of this question)

Comment: It looks like what you're trying to do would look pretty ugly. I'd endorse displaying the equation separately, either before or after the figure and `\ref` it in the caption...

Answer (score 10):

Using the package "caption":

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
    ...
    \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
    \caption[.]{
    \begin{displaymath}
        assoc\_meaning(\lambda x_{SBJ}. followed(x,y) \&actor(x) \nonumber \&actor(y),\lambda x_{SBJ}. maintained(x,\nonumber <(dist\_from(y),1))
    \end{displaymath}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

The square brackets following `\caption` *aren't* optional, but leaving them off won't cause an error that looks any different than the one before you added `\usepackage{caption}` and `\captionsetup{...}`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you do not want to use the `$ ... $` solution, because of fractions?

If so, you can use `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`.

I would try `$ \displaystyle \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot \sum_{i=0}^n i$`, i.e. use the `\displaystyle` command.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660044/typesetting-latex-fraction-terms-to-be-larger-in-an-equation contains an example of the type of formula I will include in the caption. Note that it is quite large and should not be in-lined with text.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then I would suggest to define a `\label` for the whole equation/formula and reference to it in the caption using `\eqref`, I think that's better than including such a huge formula into a figure caption.